# What happened to the "Prototype Cell" option of UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I created an app for iPad (not using StoryBoards), with a UITabBarController.  I added some labels and textfields at the top of the view.  Now, I want to add a UITableView (without the controller) to the window, which it took.  When I try to add a UITableViewCell, there is no option for Prototype Cell...

Why?  and how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Only storyboards have prototype cells. Regular non-storyboard-based `UITableView` objects in Interface Builder do not have prototype cells (static or dynamic).

Comment: Jack is correct and also, you must use a TableViewController to use Static Cell TableViews.

Comment: Damn it..  I didn't realise that.  (Sigh...)

Answer (score 1):

If using IB, and want to create your 'prototype' cell with IB, just create a new xib and lay out your cell.  Otherwise, you can create it programatically.